# Avoiding error rows during Oracle dump import

Tags: oracle, dump

I am using Oracle's `imp/exp` utility to transfer database to another server.
First I have created an empty database with the same tablespaces as the source database.

When I use `full mode` the result of the import is fine the database is working correctly but I got huge number of errors because of existing system objects.
It is fairly disturbing and I cannot check whether there are "real" error messages.
An option would be to used `ignore=Y` but according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1014036) it means the table data may be duplicated. This does not sound good. Or if I import only once there would be no duplication?

I could also use `user mode` import but it seems to me according to [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#i1004890) that important parts will not be imported this way and I think it should also be avoided.

What could be the solution?

Should I use `expdp/impdp` instead, do they solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `expdp`/`impdp` for many reasons (usability, performance, etc.). Of course, it can unload/load whole database. You can use `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` to control what should happen (`SKIP | APPEND | TRUNCATE | REPLACE`) in tables are already in the target database. You can also use `EXCLUDE` parameter to avoid import of unchanged/unwanted schema objects.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you are only interested in certain schema's and you don't want to import the system schema's. If your dump file contains a full export you can import the schema's you are interested in as follows:

```
imp system/<password>@<database> file=yourdump.dmp fromuser=<user1>,<user2>...<user_n>
```

Comment: OK, but what about roles, directory aliases, etc. that are not imported?

Comment: I cannot do this before I have created the user by hand.